# Add class to an a tag within a string using js or php

Tags: php, wordpress, html-framework-7

I am loading the content from a WordPress site into an app programmed in framework 7.  Due to this all external links break because they need to contain class="link external".  I am looking for a way to allow users to click the links and open a browser window.

There are two ways I can think of but unable to accomplish.

- js -  search the string for the a tags and add/edit the class.
- php - create filter in wordpress that modifies the link for the json 
  feed.

Some Thoughts

```
add_filter("rest_prepare_post", 'prepare_post', 10, 3);
function prepare_post($data, $post, $request){
    // Create a replace system for a tags on the following variable.
    $data['content']['rendered']
}
```

Comment: I love how everyone just down votes without suggestion or question I see why no one posts at night.

Answer (score 0):

After digging all night I found that I could add the following with the async in my routes to add the class.

```
{
    path: '/view-article/:articleId/',
    async: function (routeTo, routeFrom, resolve, reject) {
        // my ajax functions
    },
    on: {
        pageAfterIn: function (event, page) {
        $$('.articleContent a').addClass('link external');
    },
}
```